# How to run an Erlang process on the main thread?

Tags: erlang, sdl

I'm interested in making little games with Erlang. I've made a super basic [NIF](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html) binding to [SDL](https://libsdl.org/) in order to test this out. When I try to open a window with SDL, however, I get this error message:

```
Error creating window: NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread!
```

(This is on MacOS btw, hence the `NSWindow`)

**How do I ensure that my Erlang code runs on the "main thread"?**

I've tried it with running Erlang with SMP disabled, which my understanding was that then it'd run single-threaded. But I still get the same error.